# angularjs ng-repeat : only show a list off matched results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

At the moment i have a ng repeat, that repeat a set of results.

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="#trip/{{trip.id}}/overview" ng-repeat="trip in trips | filter:search | limitTo:-15">
```

Basicly my list shrinks the more i enter stuff in my input field

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.$" class="form-control input-lg">
```

What i want to achieve is that i have a result set of 0 items at start.
end the more i type into the ng-model input field the more or less items matched show up.

is there a filter for that or something to achieve my goal?

thx

Comment: Are you looking for the text input to act as an "exact match" rather than substring? That's the only way I can think of having *more* results show up after typing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you write a new filter service that handles a special case when `search.$` empty, or you could *maybe* do something like this (untested):

```
<a ... ng-repeat="trip in (search.$ ? (trips | filter:search | limitTo:-15) : [])">
```